# Is there a way to detect/prevent strings being compared with == in C#?

Tags: c#, compare, resharper, case-sensitive, code-inspection

I'd like to enforce that when strings are compared a conscious decision being made on whether the comparison is case sensitive or case insensitive as we have had several bugs raised in the system caused by this problem.

I know you can enforce a StringComparison to be used when using String.Equals() (e.g. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/SpecifyStringComparison.html).

But I can't find a way of detecting if someone simply uses val1 == val2?

Any ideas?

Comment: You can perhaps overload == operator and throw an exception when it's called or handle it as you wish.

Comment: I don't think [CA1307](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1307?view=vs-2019) fires for uses of `==` unfortunately. You could write your own Roslyn analyzer for this easily enough

Comment: You could write your own Roslyn analyzer

Comment: Bad idea. I believe you only want to do so with displayed text, anything what uses strings under the hood (e.g. dictionaries, enums, nameof, etc) doesn't have any problem with `==`.

Comment: the problem is not == comparison but the lack of testing. You should be writing unit tests that can verify that the code is working properly. Have a test were the text has some capitals and another where the text is all lower or upper and see if the code operates the way you want it to